# Why does a maximum flow in a transportation network always exist

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In a [transportation network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) the Ford Fulkerson algorithm and others are often used to determine the maximum flow. How do we know that there is such a thing as a flow which is a maximum flow in the first place?

Van Lint's book "A course in combinatorics" which I am reading from says that the maximum flow exists by "[continuity reasons](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=maximum%20flow%20in%20a%20transport%20network%20exists%20by%20continuity)". I do not understand this.

Answer (score 2):

You have some assumptions to work with here that guarantee a maximum flow (the flow is the amount, there may be many distributions of that flow across the graph that work). For one, it is typical in graph theory to assume the graph is finite unless otherwise stated (this is common but not universal, so, check with your author's conventions; hopefully they pointed that out). Additional, since you're talking about a flow network, that means you have 1 source and 1 sink. The specific reason he refers to continuity reasons is that you can represent the space of possible flows (those that abide by the constraints of the problem, maximum or not), as a convex subset of $(\mathbb{R}^+)^{|E|}$, where $|E|$ denotes the number of edges in your graph and is the 'exponent' on $\mathbb{R}^+$. Because that set is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{|E|}$, you use analysis theorems to show that there is a point on it's boundary of maximal 'distance' (distance being measured by the 'taxicab' metric, which is the sum of absolute values of the changes in each variable, not euclidean distance) from the origin (maximum flow is bounded by the constraints on edges and the finiteness of the graph).

Comment: Thank you. (1) You say that there is a space of possible flows. Can you describe this vector space? (2) What analysis theorems are you referring to? (3) Why are you invoking the taxicab metric and not the usual metric?

Comment: (1) By space I mean topological space, specifically it has the topology it gets as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{|E|}$, it is not a vector space (though it is a subset of one).

Comment: (2) Any number of fairly standard theorems about continuity (whether specific to $\mathbb{R}^{|E|}$ or more general from topology (continuity is fundamentally a topological concept). I'm not actually sure what specific theorems you're author is referring to.

Comment: (3) I'm not actually sure the taxicab metric is correct now that I think about it, but the euclidean one isn't either. What you really want to measure, is the net flow from source to sink. That can be done via measuring the flow across any cut of the graph into two disconnected pieces (why?).

Comment: So is this space a subspace of the Euclidean space? If so, then why do you talk about the taxicab metric? Won't the open sets be different?

Comment: Ok I just saw your comment,

Comment: They are actually the same, but that is not obvious or trivial to prove (though it's not hard if you know some basic theorems on Basis and Sub-basis) for topologies.